# Update a single row at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to update one row data at a time but when I am updating the data it is checking for all of the rows which are available in the grid which makes the update function very time consuming. Please help me out that how can I update one data at a time so it can save the time while updating data.

Here is the aspx file code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSystemUpdate" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridview" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="RefManupdate" HorizontalAlign="Left" OnRowCancelingEdit="RefManUpdate_GridViewCancelEdit" OnRowDeleted="RefManUpdate_GridViewDeleted" OnRowEditing="RefManUpdate_GridViewEdit" OnRowUpdated="RefManUpdate_GridViewUpdated" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="RefMan_RowDataBind" OnRowUpdating="RefMan_Updating">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="../GLImages/dgcancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="../GLImages/dgdelete.png" EditImageUrl="../GLImages/dgedit.png" SelectImageUrl="~/GLImages/fix.png" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="../GLImages/dgrefresh.png">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="90px" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="90px" />
                        </asp:CommandField>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="../GLImages/dgdelete.png" ShowDeleteButton="True">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                        </asp:CommandField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ref1" HeaderText="System" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Ref1">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AttDescription" HeaderText="System Description" SortExpression="AttDescription">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ControlStyle Font-Size="18px" Width="98%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="LocationEditDropDown" runat="server" Font-Size="18px" Width="98%">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="LocationLBL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="150px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area" SortExpression="Ref3">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="AreaEditDropDown" runat="server" Font-Size="18px" Width="98%">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="AreaLBL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ref3") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="150px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Planned Date" SortExpression="CCMS_PlannedDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="PlannedDateTextBox" Width="98%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="PlannedDateLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="120px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completion Date" SortExpression="CCMS_CompletionDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="CompletionDateTextBox" Width="98%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="CompletionDateLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="120px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Completions" HeaderText="CMP" SortExpression="Completions">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                        </asp:CheckBoxField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="White" Wrap="False" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />

                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowMatch" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowMatchSelected" />           </script>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Here it is aspx.cs file code where update function functionality written.

```
protected void RefMan_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vmdatamanagerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        GridView CurrentGridView = (GridView)sender;

        string ID = CurrentGridView.DataKeys[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].Value.ToString();

        DropDownList LocationEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].FindControl("LocationEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (LocationEditDropDown != null)
        {
            string CurrentLocation = LocationEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
            SQLFunctions.UpdateRecord("UPDATE DataRefSets set Location ='" + CurrentLocation + "' WHERE ID =" + ID);

        }

        DropDownList AreaEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].FindControl("AreaEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (AreaEditDropDown != null)
        {
            string CurrentArea = AreaEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;

            if (CurrentArea == string.Empty)
                CurrentArea = "NA";

            if (!string.Equals(SQLFunctions.GetString("Select Area from DataRefSets WHERE ID =" + ID), CurrentArea, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SQLFunctions.UpdateRecord("UPDATE DataRefSets set Area ='" + CurrentArea + "', Ref3 ='" + CurrentArea + "' WHERE ID =" + ID);
                SQLFunctions.UpdateRecord("UPDATE [DataRefSets] SET [Reference] = [ref1] + '~' + [ref2] + '~' + [ref3] + '~' + [ref4] + '~' + [ref5] + '~' + [ref6] WHERE [ID] = '" + ID + "'");
            }
        }

        DropDownList SystemEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].FindControl("SystemEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (SystemEditDropDown != null)
        {
            string CurrentSystem = SystemEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;

            if (CurrentSystem == string.Empty)
                CurrentSystem = "NA";


            if (!string.Equals(SQLFunctions.GetString("Select ref1 from DataRefSets WHERE ID =" + ID), CurrentSystem, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                SQLFunctions.UpdateRecord("UPDATE DataRefSets set ref1 ='" + CurrentSystem + "', ccmssystemno ='" + CurrentSystem + "' WHERE ID =" + ID);
                SQLFunctions.UpdateRecord("UPDATE [DataRefSets] SET [Reference] = [ref1] + '~' + [ref2] + '~' + [ref3] + '~' + [ref4] + '~' + [ref5] + '~' + [ref6] WHERE [ID] = '" + ID + "'");
            }
        }

        TextBox PlannedDateTextBox = CurrentGridView.Rows[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].FindControl("PlannedDateTextBox") as TextBox;

        if (PlannedDateTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            //string Date = Master.ConvertDateInputForUpdate(PlannedDateTextBox);
            DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(PlannedDateTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
            string sql = "UPDATE [DataRefSets] SET [CCMS_PlannedDate] = @CCMS_PlannedDate WHERE [ID] = @ID";            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCMS_PlannedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        TextBox CompletionDateTextBox = CurrentGridView.Rows[CurrentGridView.EditIndex].FindControl("CompletionDateTextBox") as TextBox;

        if (CompletionDateTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(CompletionDateTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
            string sql = "UPDATE [DataRefSets] SET [CCMS_CompletionDate] = @CCMS_CompletionDate WHERE [ID] = @ID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCMS_CompletionDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE [DataRefSets] SET [CCMS_CompletionDate] = @CCMS_CompletionDate WHERE [ID] = @ID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCMS_CompletionDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your working on ONE row of data over and over.
Thus, I would use a data row for this.

this is "air code", but from your code, you can/should use somthing like this:

```
protected void RefMan_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("vmdatamanagerConnectionString").ConnectionString;

    GridView CurrentGridView = (GridView)sender;

    string ID = CurrentGridView.DataKeys(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).Value.ToString();

    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from DataRefSets WHERE ID = " + ID, 
           new SqlConnection(connString)))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
        SqlCommandBuilder sqlU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

        DataRow myRow = rstData.Rows(0);

        DropDownList LocationEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).FindControl("LocationEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (LocationEditDropDown != null)
            myRow("Location") = LocationEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;

        DropDownList AreaEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).FindControl("AreaEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (AreaEditDropDown != null)
        {
            string CurrentArea = AreaEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (CurrentArea == string.Empty)
                CurrentArea = "NA";

            if (myRow("Area") != CurrentArea)
            {
                myRow("Area") = CurrentArea;
                myRow("Ref3") = CurrentArea;
                myRow("Reference") = Get6(myRow);
            }
        }

        DropDownList SystemEditDropDown = CurrentGridView.Rows(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).FindControl("SystemEditDropDown") as DropDownList;

        if (SystemEditDropDown != null)
        {
            string CurrentSystem = SystemEditDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (CurrentSystem == string.Empty)
                CurrentSystem = "NA";

            if (myRow("ref1") != CurrentSystem)
            {
                myRow("ref1") = CurrentSystem;
                myRow("ccmssystemno") = CurrentSystem;
                myRow("[Reference]") = Get6(myRow);
            }
        }

        TextBox PlannedDateTextBox = CurrentGridView.Rows(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).FindControl("PlannedDateTextBox") as TextBox;

        if (PlannedDateTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            DateTime MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(PlannedDateTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
            myRow("CCMS_PlannedDate") = MyDate;
        }

        TextBox CompletionDateTextBox = CurrentGridView.Rows(CurrentGridView.EditIndex).FindControl("CompletionDateTextBox") as TextBox;

        if (CompletionDateTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            DateTime MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(CompletionDateTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
            myRow("CCMS_CompletionDate") = MyDate;
        }
        else
            myRow("CCMS_CompletionDate") = DBNull.Value;

        // write row back
        da.Update(rstData);
    }
}

public string Get6(DataRow MyRow)
{
    string sCol = "";
    string sResult = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        sCol = "ref" + i;
        if (sResult != "")
            sResult += "~";
        sResult += MyRow(sCol);
    }

    return sResult;
}
```

In other words, pull the row - make changes to the row, and then save it back.

This thus replaces a WHOLE bunch of repeated update statements - which as you note going to really hit the database hard, is more code, and a lot of updates. Do your update/changes against the row, and then at the end send it back to the table as per above.